# How do you flatten an array of nested objects in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am new to the Swift language and I am struggling to find an example of how to flatten/combine an array of nested objects into a single array. E.g. Using JSON as an example I want to convert

```
[
  { 
    name: 'Steve Maddon', 
    shoes: [
      { type: 'Jimmy Choo' }, 
      { type: 'Louix Crouton' }
    ] 
  },
  { 
    name: 'Bobby Brown', 
    shoes: [
      { type: 'Adidas' }, 
      { type: 'Reebok' }
    ] 
  },
]
```

to

```
[   
  {
    name: 'Steve Maddon',
    shoeType: 'Jimmy Choo'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Steve Maddon',
    shoeType: 'Louix Crouton'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bobby Brown',
    shoeType: 'Adidas'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bobby Brown',
    shoeType: 'Reebok'
  }
]
```

I have modelled this using the following classes and objects:

```
class Shoe { 
  let type: String

  init(type: String) {
    self.type = type
  }
}

class Person {
  let name: String
  let shoes: [Shoe]

  init(name: String, shoes: [Shoe]) {
    self.name = name
    self.shoes = shoes
  }
}

let people = [
  Person(name: "Steve Maddon", shoes: [
    Shoe(type: "Jimmy Choo"),
    Shoe(type: "Louix Crouton"),
  ]),
  Person(name: "Bobby Brown", shoes: [
    Shoe(type: "Adidas"),
    Shoe(type: "Reebok"),
  ])
]
```

And I would like to flatten those objects into this data structure:

```
class PersonWithShoeType {
  let name: String
  let shoeType: String

  init(name: String, showType: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.shoeType = shoeType
  }
}
```

I was certain that `flatMap` was the function I needed but many of the examples only operate on simple arrays. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please don't tag spam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the following:

```
class PersonWithShoeType {
  let name: String
  let shoeType: String

  init(name: String, showType: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.shoeType = shoeType
  }
}

let people = [
  Person(name: "Steve Maddon", shoes: [
    Shoe(type: "Jimmy Choo"),
    Shoe(type: "Louix Crouton"),
  ]),
  Person(name: "Bobby Brown", shoes: [
    Shoe(type: "Adidas"),
    Shoe(type: "Reebok"),
  ])
]

let personWithShoes = people.flatMap({ person in 
  person.shoes.map({ shoe in
    PersonWithShoeType(name: person.name, shoeType: shoe.type)
  }) 
})
```

Note to self: RTFM first

Comment: What is `people here`? You haven't even given the complete description of the problem statement and given a solution without the relevant details.